# Manipulate a MVC4 view's DOM and generate a CSS formatted PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, abcpdf

first of all the current state:

- I have a MVC4 webapplication (online calculator) with razor engine
- the application has a resultview which shows the calculated results
- I have the abbility to use ABCPDF 8.1
- To manipulate DOM I use the HtmlAgilityPack

The goal is: inside the ResultController, get the current views html, manipulate its DOM (especially remove navigation elements) and generate a fully formatted pdf.

Following things work:

Create a fully css styled pdf from a URL

```
var document  = new Doc();
document.AddImageUrl("www.whatever.com");
return File(doc.GetData(), "application/pdf", "abc.pdf");
```

Create a pdf from a views html with manipulated DOM without the specific CSS3 formattings

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{

    // get html stream from view
    var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "WizardFirstStep", "_Layout");
    var context = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, result.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
    result.View.Render(context, sw);
    var html = sw.ToString();

    // manipulate DOM with HtmlAgilityPack
    var hdoc = new HtmlDocument();
    hdoc.LoadHtml(html);
    ... manipulation

    // create pdf and return FileContentResult
    var doc = new Doc();
    doc.AddImageHtml(hdoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
    return File(doc.GetData(), "application/pdf", "abc.pdf");
}
```

So I can create a styled html site as pdf and i can create a manipulated non-styled html file as pdf.

AddImageUrl uses css

AddImageHtml doesn't use the css

I'll be glad about every approach and solution

**//edit:**

I have a quick workaround for this problem. Instead of @Styles.Render the css relative with

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

I absolutely address the stylesheet

```
@Styles.Render("http://localhost:53406/Content/Site.css")
```

But maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: After some research I think the question is: how to render a view in mvc4 razor from a string which holds the html (without displaying the view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is MVC and everything can be controlled through URL, I say load the document as a URL rather than an image.

```
theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.google.com/")
```

This way ABCpdf loads the page the way you see it. Unless there are scripts and whatnot that control the view, then you'd need to configure the document for that.

Comment: That's right. But I'd like to manipulate the websites DOM. I want to generate a result PDF from the HTML page, but without the website related things like copyright, navigation and so on. Another way would be to copy the view, customize the template and print that HTML to pdf from a URL. But at the moment I didn't find a way to access a view by absoulte URL without showing it in the browser. I think I should start another question relating this problem.